# парсинг xml XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xml, парсер, xmlparser, fb2

Разбираюсь с анализом xml, использую для этого `XMLPullParser`. В качестве примера решил разобраться с файлом fb2 и написать читалку. Формат файла описан [тут](http://www.fictionbook.org/index.php/????????_???????_FB2_??_Sclex).

В принципе анализировать файл получается, но возникает несколько вопросов :

1. Если например скопировать файл 1.fb2 в папку raw\xml студия ругается, что у файла д.б. расширение *.xml. Почему? Можно как-то работать с файлами xml-ой структуры с использованием XMLPullParser?
2. Файл fb2 приходится редактировать перед анализом

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><FictionBook
   xmlns="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0"
   xmlns:l="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`

---

Пришлось удалить `xmlns="http://www.gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/2.0"` и сменить кодировку на UTF-8.
После этого xml-fb2 "скушался "
может кто-то сможет прокомментировать

P.S. Настройки парсера (`FEATURE_VALIDATION`, `FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL`) смотрел, но они мне не помогли, может не до конца с ними разобрался

Comment: Вы одним вопросом - почему? затрагиваете множество тем. 
Resources это жесткая структура и вы не можете хранить в папке xml файл .fb2 поэтому и ругается. Храните в assets, но там данные не имеют структуры поэтому вам придется использовать потоки для их чтения по байтам, тогда зачем усложнять и ограничивать себя, сразу читайте данные с памяти (SD) по пути, используйте xmlparser для работы с fb2. Как вариант просто измените расширения файла и положите уже в package xml, вопрос то у вас какой? в чем ошибка? что именно не получается?

Comment: Как открыть файл .fb2 c SD, сейчас получается только изменив расширение на .xml?

Comment: Если в манифесте добавляю intent-filter<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.fb2" /> и меняю расширение на .fb2, файл не открывается